# Count lines in files from set

Tags: find, batch

I need to count the number of lines in files from a set.
I tried to execute

```
find -name pattern -exec vc -l '{}' \;
```

But this command returns

```
find: `vc': No such file or directory
```

Comment: It's called `wc`. Also, change `\;` to `+` if you want to get the total count as well.

Answer (score 3):

@Gilles is right, the command is called `wc`. The following does the job:

```
find -name pattern -exec wc -l '{}' \;
```

An alternative without using `find` might also do the job:

```
wc -l pattern
```